# Need help proving the statement

Tags: proof-writing

Assume that D ⊂ N and D ̸= ∅. Prove or disprove using a detailed structured proof, justifying every step:
[∀x ∈ D, ∃y ∈ N, y < x] ⇔ [0 ̸∈ D]

I have no idea how to prove a statement like that, I'm completely stuck! If anyone could help me out in any way that would be awesome

Comment: Please describe what your symbols mean. What is $N$? What is the 0 with a slash through it? What does $D$ with a slash through it mean?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This appears to be about the [Well-Ordering Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order#Equivalent_formulations), which states that every nonempty subset $D$ of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ has a least element (where I assume that you define the natural numbers to start at $0$ instead of at $1$). That is, we know that if $D \subseteq \mathbb N$ and $D \neq \emptyset$, then:
$$
\exists y \in D \text{ such that } \forall x \in D,~  y \leq x
$$

Hence, if $y$ is allowed to be any natural number and if we want that inequality to be strict, then we want to exclude the possibility that $x = 0 \in D$ so that we can just take $y = 0$ to be the natural number that is strictly smaller than any other natural number.